# CSS other image for mobile version

Tags: css

I want to change the picture on the website, depending if it is called by desktop or mobile version.

I have following code, how can I add a line for mobile version?

```
    .page-header-area {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) url("images/bennar.gif") center center no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% auto;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 100px 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use media queries.

```
.page-header-area {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) url("images/bennar.gif") center center no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% auto;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 100px 0;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .page-header-area {
    background: url("mobile.gif")
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks, worked! Now I have problem with resizing of images:                                   
       `@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .page-header-area {
      background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) url("images/test.gif") center center no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% auto;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 100px 0;
  }`
}